# admin panel toggle part not rendering properly?

Tags: django-admin, toggle, panel

admin panel toggle part not rendering properly?
[image]

It happens sometimes that if you run multiple projects, your browser caches the admin CSS. If the cached version is from an older Django, it may look bad with 4.2.

i try that and it's work in my case

`CTRL + SHIFT + R`

Hard refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these:

1. python manage.py collectstatic - did not work for me
2. python manage.py collectstatic --clear - did not work for me
3. Downgrading from 4.2.4 to lower - did not work for me
4. Hard refresh browser - did not work for me
5. Clear cache - did not work for me

What worked for me since I have CloudFront to invalidate entire admin CSS folder, you can do it via AWS CLI or AWS Management Console:
Object path: /static/admin/css/*